# Apache - the var/www has root as owner

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have downloaded Apache on Ubuntu by following [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) tutorial. It installed the Apache nicely and it is running successfully but there is one problem which is a huge one. I do not have permissions to Write to /var/www folder although I am Administrator. The current owner of that `www` folder is **root**. I have installed Ubuntu today so I don't know much about it. I have used `chown` command but it throws error : Operation not permitted.

Can anybody tell me so that I can have Read & Write permissions?

Comment: "I have used chown command but it throws error : Operation not permitted." your forgot to put `sudo` in front of your command. And the user and group of things inside `/var/www/` should not be `root` but `apache` or `www-data` ;) (see the apache.conf or sites-enabled for the correct one).

Comment: @Rinzwind Hey, man I am reading docs. Read about `sudo`, gives us Super User priviliges. Let me run the command ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to change the ownership of the */var/www* folder, leave it as root. If you need to create new files or folders inside */var/www* leave them also under root ownership; or owned by you user if you prefer. For Apache to serve these assets all you need to do is provide read permissions to the *www-data* user:

```
sudo chmod a+r /var/www/my.asset
```

Also, consider using instead the */srv* folder to store assets that must be served by applications such as Apache.

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and type as

```
chmod 744 -R /var/www/
```

I have faced the issue too and resolved by the above command. hope that helps.

Only root user have complete permissions. Normal user and others are only able to read and can not able to write or execute.

Next with

```
chmod 754 -R /var/www/
```

root can do everything. Normal user can read and execute but can not write. other user can read but can not write and execute.

Comment: This leaves potential security issues.

Comment: other can read and execute but they cant write , so what the problem ?

Comment: this makes unix command injection possible

Comment: @Joren now ok ?

Comment: You can never be paranoid enough :)

Comment: I agree with @Joren And to nitpick even more: 664 is -more- than enough for not executables. So *html, *js etc need not be 754. (and yes I am paranoid too ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can access the files in /var/www/ easily by using nautilus as root:

```
sudo nautilus
```

I would not recommend changing ownership or permissions of the directory because of potential security risks.